# Не пойму как получить все таблицы из бд со всеми их значениями по отдельности

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

Доброго времени суток.

Не пойму как получить все таблицы из БД, получается только одну таблицу.

Кусок кода в котором я получаю таблицу

```
module.exports = function(app, connection) {
  app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM some_table;', function(err, data) {
        (err) ? res.send(err) : res.json({some_data: data});
    })
  })
}
```

Суть в чем, хочу по отдельности получить каждую таблицу из бд в виде JSON и дальше уже проводить с ними операции.

Сервер Node.js, Express, клиент React

Comment: Получи список таблиц из INFORMATION_SCHEMA, и потом выгребай их по одной, пока не кончатся. Но разумнее (схема БД меняется не так чтобы часто) сделать под это дело хранимку на сервере, да её и выполнять. А потом только рекордсеты перебирать да в файл сбрасывать. Ещё разумнее - выгрузить через хранимку прямо на сервере, а потом оттуда по FTP или как ещё загрузить.

Comment: @Akina а есть какой-нибудь мануал как сделать хранимку? У меня все на localhot`е и сервер, и клиент, и бд

Comment: *а есть какой-нибудь мануал как сделать хранимку?* Отож... [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему решил с помощью Pooling connections, об этом можно почитать [здесь](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections)